# What does ===! operator in JS mean?

Tags: javascript

What does `===!` operator in JS mean?

Just checked in the browser console,

```
5 ===! 5  //false
5 ===! 6  //false
5 ===! 7  //false
```

What's the meaning of ===!   ? Yes, three equal signs and exclamation sign thereafter. Thank you.

Or, 5 ===! 5 is treated as 5 === false ?

Comment: Hmmm... `===`  followed by `!` maybe?

Comment: Nope. Exactly as I've asked. Otherwise I won't ask, as I know ! and the difference between == and ===. Thank you.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642028/what-is-the-name-of-the-operator

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's not an operator, it's two of them. It is parsed as `5 === (!5)`, whitespace is ignored between tokens.

Comment: Hehe... thank you. So, even ===!<space>5 is treated as === !5. Didn't pay attention to that.

Comment: Yes, it's four tokens: `5`,`===`,`!`,`5`. Whitespace doesn't matter.